# Change namespace of objects in jaxb

Tags: java, namespaces, jaxb, unmarshalling

I've to manage many webservices and have to put my aplication in the middle of them and clients: clients will call me, I'll call the servers and manage the responses to send them to clients.

Both request and response have an 'envelope's defined: different but almost the same.

Lets say:

```
<req xmlns="namespaceReq">
<req-data>..different info 1..</req-data>
<info>...Info object...</info>
</req>
```

and

```
<resp xmlns="namespaceResp">
<resp-data>..different info 2...<resp-data>
<info>...Info object...</info>
</resp>
```

So I want to share common classes between request and response -aka the info object-; I've done a java package for the request (with the namespace of the request in its package-name and Req and Req-data classes), another one for the response (with the namespace of the response in its package-name, and also, Resp and Resp-data classes) and have done another package to hold the common part (the Info class) and there's my problem...

How should I manage the namespaces so that I could share the common Info object to both request and response?

If I put request's namespace in the package-info.java it works for the request but not for the response, if I put response it doesn't work for request...

Answer (score 1):

The common objects package should define its own XML namespace ... I have done the kind of configuration that you're trying to do, but I generated the objects from XSD files ... Example:

XSD Commons:

```
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="http://xyz/commons"
    xmlns:tns="http://xyz/commons"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="InfoType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XSD Requests:

```
<xs:schema
targetNamespace="http://xyz/requests"
xmlns:tns="http://xyz/requests"
xmlns:commons="http://xyz/commons"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
version="1.0"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:import namespace="http://xyz/commons" schemaLocation="commons.xsd" />

  <xs:element name="Request" type="tns:RequestType" />

  <xs:complexType name="RequestType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="info" type="commons:InfoType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem appears when I call the services and I try to bind their responses to my model and I cannot change the services because are not mine. The problem is in binding their responses to my model because they haven't got that common package. :( 

I don't think that what I wanna do is even possible.... Although being not so extrange...

Comment: This is just an idea (I haven't try it before), but may be you should check if you can extend (inheritance) the objects of your services into your own objects namespace.